# How call polymorphic for each item in loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In **Laravel 5.6** i have a polymorphic relationship .

I have many `products` in **db** and `avatars` for each `product` .

When i send `products data` to **view** i want to send avatar for every product .

I write a polymorphic relationship between avatars table and products table and i can access avatar of each product using this code easily :

```
$avatar = Product::find(id)->avatars()->first();
```

But when db result is NOT one product and is a array of products how i can access each avatar ?

If i have result like this how can i find `avatar` of each `product` in **view** file ?  :

```
$products = Product::all();
return view('frontend/home')->with([
        'products'=>$products,
    ]);
```

And in View i have something like this :

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   <li>
    @include('items.product')
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$products = Product::with('avatars')->get();
```

Then in your blade file you would have something like:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <img src="{{ $product->avatars->first()->url }}" alt="" />
@endforeach
```

Comment: nice but i want use it inside `href` attribute of `<a>` tag . when i use   `$product->avatars->first()` can't access `first()` method but  `$product->avatars` worked fine

Comment: can u help me about above problem ? `$product->avatars` returned `array()` and i want to access `url` parameter inside this `array` like this : `$product->avatars->first()->url` but i can't do in `href` attribute of `a` tag

Comment: @sam If it's an avatar I would have thought you should be using an image tag. I've updated my answer to demonstrate.